# CMD to Powershell -reconnect -install

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, attributes, reconnect

I have a batch file in windows where I run:

> run program.exe -reconnect xxxx - install

I was wondering what would be the simplest way to do the same in powershell. Any ideas?

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Is `run` really part of your command? Is `program.exe` in the PATH or is it located in the directory that the batch file is run from? Please clarify by updating your question directly.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

`.\program.exe -reconnect xxxx -install`

This assumes you're running the script from the directory program.exe is in.